# how can I empty a buffer in mips?

Tags: buffer, mips

I have a question, how can I empty a buffer? 
for example, I store a word in a buffer, the buffer size is 50
then I wanna keep this buffer, but I want it to be empty, how to erase everything in the buff?

Comment: Write N zero-bytes to it (where N is the size of the buffer).

Comment: zero-bytes means nul in the ascii?

Comment: It means the value zero, as in `li $t1,0`.

Answer (score 1):

Just store `0` over the whole size of the buffer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @OlivierH: Why not? It tells the OP what needs to be done, and it should be trivial for him/her to write the assembly implementation.